# Import libraries in Android studio project to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have a Android Studio project and I want the same in Eclipse. So I created a sample project in Eclipse and copied the files in `java` folder of Android Studio to `src` folder in Eclipse. I also copy pasted the `res` and Manifest of Android Studio to Eclipse.

Now, I have some errors in java files in `src` folder due to some missing libraries. I know its because of the missing libraries in Eclipse and i want to import them from Android Studio project. But in Android project, I am not able to find the libraries. Maybe they are in `build.gradle` script. How do I get these libraries and use in my Eclipse project?

Comment: One way is to manually get the jar files/source of the libraries and add them in your eclipse, libs folder.

Comment: I am not able to find any jar files/source of libraries in the Android Studio project

Comment: go to build.gradle file in android studio and search dependancies in web and get jar, add them to lib in Eclips.

Comment: search your lib in http://gradleplease.appspot.com/ and add dependencies  compile =)

Comment: Also you can view in `build\intermediates\exploded-aar` in file explorer to view your libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find android jars from your sdk like **android-support-design** from **sdk\extras\android\support\design\libs** and do more.

External jars like **retrofit**, **okhttp** and more

[http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/CatalogJar.htm)